# Filename is getting from a Fileuploader

Tags: c#, asp.net

Filename is not getting from a fileuploader.I upload the image from a fileuploader and load that image in a box,at that point it work fine.but when i try to save it, i didn't get that filename from fileuploader

```
<div class="box box-right" style="width:19%">                          
    <div>
     <asp:Image  ID="Avatar" runat="server" Height="157px"  Width="177px"    /> 
    </div>
    <div class="button">
     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" style="width:169px" onchange="previewFile()" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In aspx page :

```
fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
    string fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    newfile = "images/" + fileName;
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + strname);
}
```

Comment: you haven't provided what exception or error you are getting ?

Comment: @ArunPratap i not getting any exception but in this  fileName = FileUpload1.FileName; i did't get the filename name

Comment: *var fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName*

Comment: If you're clicking the save button later on, remember you're working with a new instance of the page class.

Comment: `i did't get the filename name` What **did** you get?

Answer (score 0):

you haven't provided what exception or error you are getting and u r saying that u r `not Using Update Panel`

THen you can do that in `c#` like this

in aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />       
</form>
```

in your code behind

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);               
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

or through `javascript` like this

```
var fileName = document.getElementById("<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>");
```

or

```
var fileName = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value;
```

Comment: i can;t enter to if loop

Comment: have u tried the same code that i have posted in my answer?

Comment: i running with the same code that you provided..i am not using  update panel

Comment: i m not getinng what going wrong there becouse its working at my machine you can go through this https://www.aurigma.com/upload-suite/developers/aspnet/how-to-upload-files-in-aspnet

Answer (score -1):

FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + strname);

you used this line and for saving file u used "strname" ...Now i couldn't see strname getting value anywhere in the code.

You have this

```
fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
    string fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

so shouldn't u use

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + fileName );
```